# Where is it more likely to find the Weapon pre-igniter augmentation?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I have found this augment a couple of times while playing FTL. Each time it has been a breeze when it came down to fights with this augment.

Anybody has any idea as to which sectors is more likely to carry this augment in stores or as reward?

Comment: most likely its a random find

Comment: Although augments are generated randomly, some sectors are more likely to have augments, and so these sectors are also more likely to have the weapon pre-igniter.

Comment: ok then which sectors are those?

Comment: I don't know, there's a couple levels of indirection in the data to figure it out and I'm too lazy to do it myself. That's why I made a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The weapon pre-igniter can be found from both the randomly generated stores (which in turn have randomly generated inventories) and as a random reward from encounters.

Due to this it is not possible to predict where they will appear in an individual game.

Comment: For the lack of better information, I guess this is the best answer for this question.